# Create Symbolic Link as Regular user

Tags: symbolic-link

I need to create a Symlink that lives in user roaming AppData, and points to a folder on another local drive, which is user specific. I have tried both `mklink` and `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink` in PowerShell 5 and both require admin rights, which makes it pretty useless in this context.
I also tried putting the user environment variable in the path, like this D:\C4R\%username%, but that doesn't work either.
Is there a mechanism for doing SymLinks as a regular user? Or is the whole concept of SymLinks really an admin thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `/J` option

```
mklink /J <link> <target>
```

I don't know powershell, but this seems to work as well:

```
New-Item -Name <link> -ItemType Junction -Value <source>
```

Comment: @T Nierath That still requires elevated privileges. This page (https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html) suggest that there is simply no way to do a SymLink without elevated privileges, but that seems kind, limiting.

Comment: It really doesn't, try it out! Because you are creating a junction, not a symlink. I don't know why there is a difference, but junctions don't need admin rights, I just created one in my AppData dir to something on D:\ no problem.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had copied a PS1 and shortcut to create a new test jig, and I hadn't noticed that the shortcut was set to Run as Administrator, so THAT was triggering the password, not the mklink IN the PS1. Now to find a way to run mklink without all the cruft in the console.

Comment: Good to hear, I added a powershell solution.